# Count the number of a number in the picture area

Tags: code-golf, number, image-processing

Your goal is to write a full program or function that takes 5 positive integers   and a string with an image filename as input `[X1,Y1], [X2,Y2], N, image.jpg` in any reasonable format, where:

- First couple `[X1,Y1]` are the top left `X`,`Y` coordinates (`<=20`) of the blue rectangle area in the example picture (`16,11`).
- Second couple `[X2,Y2]` are the bottom right `X`,`Y` coordinates (`<=20`) of the blue rectangle area in the example picture (`20,22`).
- Fifth number `N` such `0 <= N <= 9` is the number that has to be found.
- Sixth parameter is a string with the filename of this [JPG picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afIkv.png).

Output how many of `N`'s are present in the indicated area (outlined in blue in the picture for this example):

[image]

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6cCZ.png) to obtain a bigger clean version of the same image.

In the picture there are 500 numbers from `0` to `9` (included) arranged in 20 columnns per 25 rows, in monospaced `Courier New` font.
Each different number has a different color (you can take advantage of this fact or ignore it and consider or convert the image in monocrome if that helps you).

**Test cases:**

```
[4,4],[13,5],1,image.jpg    > 4  (outlined in red)
[4,4],[13,5],4,image.jpg    > 2  (outlined in red)
[17,5],[17,5],2,image.jpg   > 1  (outlined in magenta)
[17,5],[17,5],9,image.jpg   > 0  (outlined in magenta)
[20,8],[20,9],3,image.jpg   > 1  (outlined in cyan)
[20,8],[20,9],2,image.jpg   > 0  (outlined in cyan)
[16,11],[20,22],0,image.jpg > 8  (outlined in blue)
[16,11],[20,22],3,image.jpg > 9  (outlined in blue)
[3,14],[11,20],7,image.jpg  > 6  (outlined in green)
[3,14],[11,20],5,image.jpg  > 6  (outlined in green)
[3,14],[11,20],8,image.jpg  > 8  (outlined in green)
[1,1],[20,25],0,image.jpg   > 47 (whole picture)
[1,1],[20,25],8,image.jpg   > 50 (whole picture)
[1,1],[20,25],1,image.jpg   > 55 (whole picture)
```

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- You must take as input this [JPG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6cCZ.png).
- You are not allowed to hardcode the matrix of numbers represented in the JPG, or the results.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Mathematica, 92 bytes

```
Count[Take[Characters@StringSplit@TextRecognize@Binarize[Import@#4,.9],#2,#],ToString@#3,2]&
```

Unnamed function taking the arguments in this format: `[{X1,X2}, {Y1,Y2}, N, "image.jpg"]`. (Indeed, the fourth argument can be either the local file name or the URL `http://i67.tinypic.com/6qh5lj.jpg`.)

`Import@#4` imports the image file, `Binarize[...,.9]` darkens all of the numbers to black, and `TextRecognize` (the function clearly doing the heavy lifting here!) extracts a multi-line string from the resulting image, which is split into a nested list of characters with `Characters@`.

`Take[...,#2,#]` keeps only the characters corresponding to the outlined rectangle, and `Count[...,ToString@#3,2]` counts the number of occurrences of `N` in the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 + pillow + pytesseract, 239 bytes

```
from PIL.Image import*
from pytesseract import*
def c(a,b,n,f):w,h=b[0]-a[0]+1,b[1]-a[1]+1;return len([1for i in range(h*w)if image_to_string(open(f).convert('L').point(lambda x:[9,0][x<250],'1')).split()[i//w+a[1]-1][i%w+a[0]-1]==str(n)])
```

This is horribly inefficient as for each number tile, the whole file is parsed. The much faster and slightly longer **243 bytes** solution would be

```
from PIL.Image import*
from pytesseract import*
def c(a,b,n,f):s=image_to_string(open(f).convert('L').point(lambda x:[9,0][x<250],'1')).split();w,h=b[0]-a[0]+1,b[1]-a[1]+1;return len([1for i in range(h*w)if s[i//w+a[1]-1][i%w+a[0]-1]==str(n)])
```